# is this bad design? MVVM pattern w/ many commands on single class

Tags: wpf, mvvm

There are two common command implementations I've seen by Microsoft. One, given by [Josh Smith here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), 
places commands onto viewmodel classes. Another, given by [Robert McCarter here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx), makes commands accessible via a static class (so we can data-bind to them with x:Static). McCarter's approach relies more on the use of singletons and static calls than I want to take chances with, so currently I've chosen to use Josh Smith's approach. However, my "main" viewmodel has blown up in size with at least 30 commands now, as I have a Ribbon control in the main window.  Is this a sign of bad design i.e. a lack of separation of concerns? or is this common for MVVM apps? It just seems like a lot of responsibility for a single viewmodel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it really matters if you have many commands in the same ViewModel. Commands are just boilerplate code, they don't really implement anything. If the actual implementation of these commands is in the same ViewModel, however, it could be an issue. You should probably try to break down your class into several components to apply the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ribbon control with a lot of commands on it, you're going to need to have a class that exposes all of those commands as properties.  It doesn't necessarily have to be your view model; you could, for instance, create a ribbon view model and then expose an instance of it from your view model.

You can't really separate the concerns here unless you have commands on your ribbon that don't interoperate with the view model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried of having many command on you MainWindow ViewModel and using a ribbon, you could try giving a separate ViewModel for every tab you have.

In an application I'm currently developing, for example, I separated each ribbon tab into a separate UserControl (which extends RibbonTabItem, because I'm using the Fleent Ribbon). Those views have their on ViewModels. Actually, those ViewModels are dependency injected using a MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) importing constructor, as well as the tabs are dependecy injected to the MainWindow using its importing constructor. While this approach is probably a gigantic overkill, it has some flexibily. Note that referencing to command on a certain tab from the MainWindow itself isn't a problem, because the MainWindow's ViewModel can have a tab's ViewModel dependency injected into itself and expose some commands of it; or some command can come in form of a specific ViewModel that is injected into all the ViewModels that need it (the latter is probably the cleaner...)